# Playing an .mp4 in one UITableView Static Cell with MoviePlayer Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a UITableView Controller with static cells; the first UITableView cell has a UIButton that, when pressed, plays a video thanks to the MoviePlayer Controller.

What I initially did was create a custom UITableView Cell class in which I implemented the MPC, then created an IBAction for the button to trigger the movie play. When I do this I get the error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

I have not used MoviePlayerController with UITableView before. What am I doing wrong?

```
-(IBAction)playvideo { 
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my_mov1" ofType:@"mp4"]]; 
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url]; 
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];
    playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;         
    [playercontroller.moviePlayer play]; 
}
```

Comment: The error says the parameter is nil. Have you checked the string?

Comment: This is what I have:     -(IBAction)playvideo {
    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my_mov1" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
     [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];
    playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [playercontroller.moviePlayer play];
}
How else can I check the string? Thanks for your help,

Comment: Make sure that [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my_mov1" ofType:@"mp4"] is not nil

Answer (score 0):

The video doesn't exist in you main bundle. Make sure you have a video that is correctly named `"my_mov1.mp4"` and make sure it is being copied into your main bundle.

You can check if a file exists by using the file manager

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL isDirectory;
NSString *filePath; // set your file path here;
BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:&isDirectory];
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try this tomorrow and see if it works. I'll let you know. I did copy the video in "Copy Bundle Resources" twice, but I'll try once more.

Comment: I tried this and it still did not work. Also, I seem to be having several other problems that are popping up now with this issue that may merit a completely new question.